# Can't upgrade "filesystem" package in Arch

Tags: arch-linux

I was unable to upgrade filesystem to latest version, `/lib` and `/lib64` exists.

And I can't just remove the link, otherwise all binaries would fail to run,

Any thought?

```
# pacman -S filesystem
:: filesystem is in IgnorePkg/IgnoreGroup. Install anyway? [Y/n] 
resolving dependencies...
looking for inter-conflicts...

Targets (1): filesystem-2013.01-3

Total Installed Size:   0.31 MiB
Net Upgrade Size:       0.21 MiB

Proceed with installation? [Y/n] 
(1/1) checking package integrity                          [###############################] 100%
(1/1) loading package files                               [###############################] 100%
(1/1) checking for file conflicts                         [###############################] 100%
error: failed to commit transaction (conflicting files)
filesystem: /lib exists in filesystem
filesystem: /lib64 exists in filesystem
Errors occurred, no packages were upgraded.
```

Comment: https://www.archlinux.org/news/update-filesystem-201301-1-and-glibc-217-2-together/ This should help.

Comment: Partial upgrades are unsupported...

Comment: @schaiba that link does solved the problem! thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That issue was pointed out when the symbolic link `/lib` was moved to another package.

**[Update filesystem-2013.01-1 and glibc-2.17-2 together](https://www.archlinux.org/news/update-filesystem-201301-1-and-glibc-217-2-together/)**

> Due to moving of the /lib symlink from the glibc package to the more
>   appropriate filesystem package, it is required to update glibc-2.17-2
>   and filesystem-2013.01-1 together. This will happen automatically when
>   you run `pacman -Syu`. Remember, partial updates are not supported and
>   never use the `--force` option.
>
> A potential issue with the upgrade on x86_64 is finding conflicting
>   files in `/usr/lib64`. All Arch Linux packages that had files in this
>   directory have been updated, so update these individually first. Any
>   AUR packages with files in this directory should be updated to install
>   them in `/usr/lib`.

Answer (score 1):

*This solution is not exactly for the problem described in the question ([but for this one](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/79453/pacman-syu-fails-bin-exists-in-filesystem/79455#79455)), but it might be of some help anyway.*

Usually the update failure is caused by some other packages, which need to be updated before you can update the `filesystem` package. So update like this:

```
$ sudo -s
# pacman -Syu --ignore filesystem,bash
# pacman -S bash
# pacman -Su
```

The first command is just to make sure that we have a root-shell open in case `sudo` gets broken during the update. The second command updates all packages except the `filesystem` package and the last one finally updates `filesystem`.

**If you use AUR or self compiled packages:** Keep in mind that also files from AUR packages or unmaintained files can cause conflicts with `filesystem`! Assuming the `filesystem` update fails with something like this:

```
filesystem: /bin exists in filesystem
filesystem: /sbin exists in filesystem
filesystem: /usr/sbin exists in filesystem
```

you should check for AUR packages or unmaintained files in `/bin`, `/sbin` and `/usr/sbin` using the following commands:

```
grep '^\(bin\|sbin\|usr/sbin\)' /var/lib/pacman/local/*/files | cut -d ":" -f 1 | uniq | cut -d "/" -f 6
```

lists all packages that hold files in any of these directories and

```
find /bin /sbin /usr/sbin -exec pacman -Qo -- {} + >/dev/null
```

lists all files in these directories that don't belong to any package.

Update the AUR packages and/or move the unmaintained files to /usr/local/... and the update of `filesystem` should work.

*Thx to [jasonwryan](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/6761/jasonwryan) for correcting my answer.*

Comment: This is a different issue (check the date of the OP) and even then the instructions you have provided are wrong. See http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/79453/pacman-syu-fails-bin-exists-in-filesystem/79455#79455

Comment: Ok I see that this is a different issue, sry for that. But how are my instructions wrong? I don't see any big difference to your solution in the the other post. Can you please explain what exactly I'm doing wrong?

Comment: If you don't also ignore bash in the first upgrade, your initrd won't be properly regenerated and next boot will fail...

Comment: Ah ok, didn't thought of that - thx for the hint :) However, the solution above worked for me, but maybe I was just lucky. Guess it's a good idea to delete my answer here to ensure that no one gets it wrong...

Comment: Just edit it so that it is correct--that way if someone does stumble across it, it will work for them. I removed my downvote to reflect that.