# Pacman -Syu fails because /usr/bin/easy_install exists in filesystem

Tags: filesystems, pacman, manjaro

`Pacman -Syu fails because /usr/bin/easy_install exists in filesystem`

Now I read on google plus that if you move easy_install out of the bin, it will work, I don't want to do that, why doing that? it's not a solution, it's a hack. [I also read this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/79453/pacman-syu-fails-bin-exists-in-filesystem), so I tried

`pacman -Syu --ignore filesystem,bash`

Still fails, same exact error. I want to know why this is happening, I've been on Mangaro for years and I have never had such an issue, and why Pacman isn't ignoring the filesystem?

Perhaps the solution is just moving `easy_install` out, but that's like taking pain killers to heal a broken arm. And indeed everything is working after moving easy_install out, but that's not the question, and why easy_install? the silliest and most useless package of all perhaps.

Comment: It sounds like ``easy_install`` is an orphan on your system (it is not owned by any package) which will cause ``pacman`` to fail out to avoid overwriting things that it shouldn't touch. How did you get ``easy_install`` there?

Comment: @HalosGhost frankly i don't know, i mean i remember doing `pip instal easy_install` but pip doesn't store stuff in `usr/bin` afaik so really i don't know, I think I'll remove it

Comment: If you used ``pip`` as root, it may very well have done so. You can use ``pacman`` to check what package on your local system owns a file (see ``man pacman`` for how); do so for this file. I suspect you will find that you installed it system-wide through ``pip``, which is a sure-fire way to break things. The solution: uninstall it using whatever tool you used to install it (i.e., ``pip``) and then continue with using ``pacman`` normally.